# How should I calculate z-score? Two groups with repeated measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, z-score

In my experimental design I have two groups, Control and Experimental, both with Pretest and Posttest measurements. I want to calculate the zscore to be able to generate a composite zscore from different psychometric tests.

I'm not sure how I should calculate the z-score to compare both groups between pre-test and post-test. Should I calculate the z-score of the two groups and pre and post all together? or should I do it all separately, calculate a z-score for each group each instance?

Additionally, another analysis we do is with the Delta (Posttest-Pretest). In that case, should I calculate the z-score for Control and Experimental separately or for both groups together?

Comment: Please explain why you want to compute a z score at all.  It's particularly puzzling in the context of your pretest-posttest comparison, because separate z-score calculations compel both group means to be zero, leading to a foregone (but useless) conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Working backwards: separate z-scores for two groups, and even more for four groups, are a bad idea, because then you throw away all the information on possibly different level and spread between Pretest and Posttest, and/or between Control and Experimental, which should (presumably) be the main statistical focus as well as the main scientific focus.

But why do you want to calculate z-scores at all? Usually keeping the units of measurement in the original data helps the scientist interpret the data more easily.
It is certainly valuable for comparing results with other studies in the same field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We calculate z-score to put together a composite of different psychometric tests that give us different types of scores. That is why having a common unit to compare and assemble a composite makes this comparison easier for us.

So the correct calculation of the zscore would be to do it from all our data together, is that correct?

Comment: There is nothing in your question about using a bundle of different measures. So the first step is to edit your question to make it clearer what you are doing. In any case, the danger with z-scores is just that you throw away information you want to keep.